# Cannot acces raw sensor data on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sensors

I am trying to retrieve raw sensor data from my phone's IMU, and while I can access the corrected version:

```
mAccelerometer = mSensorManager?.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
Log.d(TAG, "Acc object: $mAccelerometer") // non-null
```

The `TYPE_ACCELEROMETER_UNCALIBRATED` does not seem exposed by the API:

```
mAccelerometer = mSensorManager?.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER_UNCALIBRATED);
Log.d(TAG, "Acc object: $mAccelerometer") // null

val sensorList =  mSensorManager?.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER_UNCALIBRATED);
Log.d(TAG, "Sensor list: $sensorList")
Log.d(TAG, "Sensor list size: ${sensorList?.size}") // 0
```

I tried adding some permissions to my `manifest.xml`:

```xml
<uses-feature android:name=" android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />
<uses-feature android:name=" android.hardware.sensor.gyroscope" />
```

but to no avail.

Am I proceeding wrongly, or is it possible the OEM disabled the API? My phone is a Huawei p10 lite, if that helps...

Comment: It is possible that for some reason Huawei did not implement access to the uncalibrated sensor data. 

Uses feature is not a permission. You can use this to make your app only available to devices that include the accelerometer by setting the <uses-feature> flag to true. You do not need a permission to access sensor data.
<uses-feature android:name=" android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" />

Comment: @Chrystian That's what I feared, thanks...! I suppose rooting would not necessarily help as this depends on why this is not implemented (i.g. is it at the API level, or at the system level)?
Do you know if there's any place that summarizes this kind of information (maybe XDA)?

Comment: Rooting will be pointless. It sounds like it was not implemented. Having super user access will make no difference. I do not know of any meaningful resources like what you are looking for.